# string value always shows nil in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have upgraded to Xcode 5.0. And when I run an app in debug mode and try to print an  `NSString` value in console, it gives me the below error. Any ideas?

```
error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): Couldn't load '_cmd' because its value couldn't be evaluated
Couldn't materialize struct: the variable 'stringValue' has no location, it may have been optimized out
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

Here is the code:

```
NSString *stringValue = [[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"merchant_name"];
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are debugging?

Comment: NSString *stringValue = [[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"merchant_name"]; when i tried to print po stringValue it gives me the above error

Comment: What is "i" counter? Are you sure you have "merchant_name" in your dic? Try some debugging.

Comment: yes i did try and  NSString has got the value. its just not displaying the value in console

Comment: use `objectForKey` instead of `valueForKey`, could you give us : `NSLog(@"%@", _responseArray);` please ?

Comment: I have seen a similar error before when breaking on the first line of enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, first time works ok, second time throws this error, presumably because when inside the block, has no reference to external variables is my guess?

Answer (score 81):

The reason is stated in the error message: *it may have been optimized out*.. this means that you are compiling and running your code in an optimized manner.

you gotta change your compiler optimization level from `Fastest,Smallest` to `none`:

- go to your target build settings
- search for optimization level
- change it to none (whatever mode you are in ie debugging, distribution or release)
- profit

do the same for your project settings

Comment: I'm suffering that same issue. Changing compiler optimization level won't work for me. The problem only appears while trying to debug code that belongs to a library my app uses (The library is included into my project and compiled by myself). I changed the optimizations settings in the library project, library target, main app project and main app target with no luck.

Comment: There are many ways this can occur. For me it was because the "Other C Flags" value was set to "-O2", even for the debug build. Turning this off for the debug build resolved the issue.

Comment: @abbood thanks.. its help me a lot, I just want to know to changing optimisation level to none will it effect on performance.??

Comment: @TapasPal naturally it would.. you want fullest optimization level for your production scheme

Answer (score 38):

Make sure you are in debug mode. Go **Edit Scheme** > **Build Configuration** > Debug

Comment: The problem is it does print NsArray and other values. only in this case it gives that error. Moreover i am getting this error after upgrading to Xcode5. Looks like its a compiler error.

Comment: @Arun it's not a compiler error, it's just a compiler setting.. see my answer

Answer (score 9):

You might be trying to debug in the "release Scheme". Go to "Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme" and pick the "run" in the left panel. Then change the build configuration to "debug".

Answer (score 4):

One alternate answer: instead of fixing "it may have been optimized out" by removing the optimization, you can stop it from being optimized by using the variable.

So, in your question, if you do something with `stringValue`:

```
NSString *stringValue = [[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"merchant_name"]; 
NSLog(@"%@", stringValue);
```

`stringValue` will no longer be optimized out because you're using it.

If you want to see all instances of optimized-out variables in your project, Use **Product** -> **Analyze** to analyze your project.  Any "Dead store" warnings (in which a value is stored, and never read) will be optimized out at compile time if you have compiler optimization turned on.

Answer (score -1):

This error seems to be showing for me despite being in debug mode with 0 optimization level. Seems to be an LLDB issue: https://discourse.llvm.org/t/debugging-swift-is-just-awful/67866