# UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage get nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Hey guys I'm doing some image editing with UIImagePickerController. Here is some code in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`:

```
    UIImage *editedImg = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:editedImg];
    CGRect imgFrm = imgView.frame;
    float rate = imgFrm.size.height / imgFrm.size.width;
    imgFrm.size.width = size;
    imgFrm.size.height = size * rate;
    imgFrm.origin.x = 0;
    imgFrm.origin.y = (size - imgFrm.size.height) / 2;
    [imgView setFrame:imgFrm];

    UIView *cropView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size)];
    [cropView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cropView addSubview:imgView];

    UIImage *croppedImg = [MyUtil createUIImageFromUIView:cropView];
```

The above is to set the image in a size*size view and draw a image from a view when the height of the image returned by picker is smaller than size.

Here is the code of `createUIImageFromUIView:(UIView*)view` :

```
+ (UIImage *)createUIImageFromUIView:(UIView *)view
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, 2.0);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

**My problem is** : when debugging, the 'editedImg'(defined in first line) just shows 'nil'. But, the following code works well. I get the corpView(shows 'nil' too) correctly and get cropped image and can encode it to base64 encoded string for sending to server side. *I just want to know why the editedImg is nil(returned by [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage], but when I choose to print the info in debug mode, the output is not nil in the console)?*

Comment: I guess you want `CGSize imgSize = croppedImg.size` !

Comment: @Maulik, thanks for the reply. I'm sorry I didn't up the definition of the 'size', it's a float value(320).

Comment: didn't get you, can you be more specific about your requirement

Comment: @Maulik, I want to do some size check to determine if I need to compress the image before sending to server side(I need it to be smaller than 1MB). But if I get nil, I cannot do that.

Comment: @Maulik, I finally knew the reason. Such a fool was I... Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I accidentally found this : [string value always shows nil in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111062/string-value-always-shows-nil-in-objective-c)

This is the reason why I always see 'nil' in debug mode while the code works well.

Answer (score 1):

The editdImg gets nil, try:

```
UIImage *editedImg = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

Get file size：

```
- (long long) fileSizeAtPath:(NSString*) filePath{
  NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
      return [[manager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil] fileSize];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Best wishes!

Comment: Hi @wormlxd, thanks for the answer. I found that it was just my mistake. Read my own answer please. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your cropped image size by

```
UIImage *croppedImg = [MyUtil createUIImageFromUIView:cropView];
NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImg);
```

Now you can check length

```
if (dataForImage.length)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the way to make NSData from UIImage and the way to check the size. But if the corppedImg is nil, I can not do enything.

Comment: @Sabbath: your question is `I just want to know how can I get the size(lenth?) of the cropped image so that I can make some compression if necessary?` No ?

Comment: @Sabbath: OR you wanted to know that why your `createUIImageFromUIView` method returning nil ?